# Replace Nth occurrence of a word (substring) in a string in R, N is the value of an integer column

Tags: r

I want to find the Nth occurence of a word in an utterance and put [brackets] around it.
I tried with various things but I think the closest I'm getting is with gsub but I can't have {copy-1} for the number of times in my regex.
Any ideas? Can we put a variable in there? Thanks!

```
#creating my df
utterance <- c("we are not who we think we are", "they know who we are")
df <- data.frame(utterance)
df$occurences = str_count(df$utterance, "we")
df <- df %>% mutate(ID = row_number())
df <- df %>% uncount(occurences) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(copy = row_number()) 

#this is my gsub
gsub("((?:we){copy-1}.*)we", "\\[we\\]", df$utterance)
```

This would be my result

```
    utterance                         ID  copy
    <chr>                          <int> <int>
1 [we] are not who we think we are     1     1
2 we are not who [we] think we are     1     2
3 we are not who we think [we] are     1     3
4 they know who [we] are               2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just this:

```
library(tidyverse)

f <- function(s,c,target) {
 g = gregexpr(target,s)[[1]][c]
 if(is.na(g) | g<0) return(s)
 paste0(str_sub(s,1,g-1),"[",target,"]",str_sub(s,1+g+length(target)))
}

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(utterance = f(utterance,copy, "we"))
```

Output:

```
  utterance                           ID  copy
  <chr>                            <int> <int>
1 [we] are not who we think we are     1     1
2 we are not who [we] think we are     1     2
3 we are not who we think [we] are     1     3
4 they know who [we] are               2     1
```

Note that this will also find `targets` that are not whole words. For example the second of occurrence of "we" in "We went where we went yesterday" is the first two letters of "went", not the second occurrence of the word "we".  If  you want to restrict to whole words, you can update the gregexpr() call to this:

```
 g = gregexpr(paste0("\\b",target, "\\b"),s)[[1]][c]
```

Comment: This is perfect! What is the [[1]] for after the gregexpr?

Comment: gregexpr returns a list for each element in `x`, (in this case `s`). Since `s` is only one element long (i.e. one string), we know we can take the first one.

Comment: I think the `gregexpr()` call should be updated to restrict `target` to whole words only?  See edit

Comment: I just had to change the last part for "str_sub(s,3+g+length(target))". I don't fully understand why, but it works with a 2 chr target but not with the 4 I was searching (nous)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a string splitting approach.  We can split the input string on `we`, and then piece together, using `[we]` as the nth connector.

```r
repn <- function(x, find, repl, n) {
    parts <- strsplit(x, paste0("\\b", find, "\\b"))[[1]]
    output <- paste0(
        paste0(parts[1:n], collapse=find),
        repl,
        paste0(parts[(n+1):length(parts)], collapse="we")
    )

    return(output)
}

x <- "we are not who we think we are"
repn(x, "we", "[we]", 1)
repn(x, "we", "[we]", 2)
repn(x, "we", "[we]", 3)

[1] "[we] are not who we think we are"
[1] "we are not who [we] think we are"
[1] "we are not who we think [we] are"
```

Comment: This is working well one by one, but I cant make it work on a 10000 row df... something like df <- df %>% mutate(test = repn(utterance, "we", "[we]", df$copy)) or
df$test = repn(df$utterance, "we", "[we]", df$copy)?

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauchamp You may try using `lapply`: `df$test <- lapply(df$copy, function(x) repn(x, "we", "[we]", 1))`

Comment: ...that's a totally different problem, not related to your original question or my answer.  I suggest researching SO and if you can't resolve it, then open a new question.

Comment: Ok sorry, With this: df$test <- lapply(df$utterance, function(x) repn(x, "we", "[we]", 1)) only the first we is bracketed in every copy. Can I change the "1" for a an expression referring to the number in df$copy?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mixed approach using a number of additional packages:

```
library(data.table)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  separate_rows(utterance, sep = " ") %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  mutate(wordcount = ifelse(utterance == "we", rleid(rowid), NA), # simpler: wordcount = ifelse(utterance == "we", 1, NA)
         wordcount = cumsum(!is.na(wordcount))) %>% 
  mutate(utterance = ifelse(utterance == "we" & wordcount == copy, paste0("[", utterance, "]"), utterance)) %>% 
  summarise(utterance = paste0(utterance, collapse = " ")) %>%
  bind_cols(.,df[,2:3])
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  rowid utterance                           ID  copy
  <int> <chr>                            <int> <int>
1     1 [we] are not who we think we are     1     1
2     2 we are not who [we] think we are     1     2
3     3 we are not who we think [we] are     1     3
4     4 they know who [we] are               2     1
```